# Jmeter - из цикла запросов собрать данные в один массив

Tags: jmeter

Всем привет! Я в jmeter выполняю цикл запросов HTTP Request (несколько потоков), получаю каждый раз json, парсю его Regular Expression Extractor, получая значение нужного поля. 
Вопрос такой: как мне собирать эти значения и записывать в массив (или в файл), чтоб по окончании сценария иметь набор таких вот данных. Короче, нужно из каждого запроса брать значение поля и сохранять.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое - [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables). Добавляете в файл *user.properties* строку вида

```
sample_variables=foo
```

и перезапускаете JMeter. В следующий раз, когда запустите тест JMeter будет сохранять значение переменной `foo` для каждого запроса в колонку в конце .jtl файла. Поменяйте `foo` на что-там-у-вас-в-поле **Reference Name**.

---

Вообще, использовать регулярки для работы с JSON не самая лучшая идея, начиная с [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) есть [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), язык [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) намного приятней и проще.

Comment: Спасибо большое